# Cakephp in subdirectory and hyperlinks

Tags: cakephp

Ive installed cakephp at my domain (non root folder) and its working perfect but i see its generating all hyperlinks as [http://www.mysite.com/mywebsite/anypage] . 
Any idea how to force it to not generate such and instead just point to desired section as if it were on root?
I believe others have asked about this without any luck in the past, i do hope a solution can come up this time :)

Resuming: Index.php is generating

```
<a href= directory/page.php>
```

and i would like to have it

```
<a href= page.php>
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use html helper for generating urls. $this->webroot can also be helpful
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::url